# C# MongoDb - Output id field properly?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I don't understand how can I output id properly when displaying objects. It's either `ObjectId()` that I can't parse back to object or some object that has id in it that I can parse but it looks weird.

Note that mapping it to class is not an option, it needs to be fully dynamic because different users have different fields.

**Code**

```
public List<object> Get()
{
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
    var server = client.GetServer();
    var database = server.GetDatabase("api_test");
    var collection = database.GetCollection("users");

    var json = collection.FindAllAs<BsonDocument>().ToJson(new JsonWriterSettings { OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict });
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(json);

    return obj;
}
```

**Example**

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "528e7f9bb1fece903aa9b246"
        },
        "Name": "Steve",
        "Age": 60
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "528e7fabb1fece903aa9b247"
        },
        "Name": "Alice",
        "Age": 44
    }
]
```

**What I would like**

```
[
    {
        "_id": "528e7f9bb1fece903aa9b246",
        "Name": "Steve",
        "Age": 60
    },
    {
        "_id": "528e7fabb1fece903aa9b247",
        "Name": "Alice",
        "Age": 44
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by explicitly updating your query result to convert `_id` to a string before it's serialized to JSON:

```
var docs = test.FindAll().ToList();
foreach (var doc in docs)
{
    doc["_id"] = doc["_id"].ToString();
}
var json = docs.ToJson(
    new JsonWriterSettings { OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict });
```